# create new row and column by summing multiple column and row

Tags: r, data.table

I'm not sure what the title should be, maybe other users can edit it. Thanks.

I have a data:

```
date    sum.A_1  sum.A_2  sum.A_3  sum.B_1  sum.B_2  sum.B_3
201101  245726   7951     81732    172      344      172
201102  1066407  34094    371868   793      1586     793
201103  1608750  51527    557677   1203     2406     1203
```

I want to create **1 new row** and **2 new columns**.
The result is like:

```
date    sum.A_1  sum.A_2  sum.A_3  sum.B_1  sum.B_2  sum.B_3   SUM.A    SUM.B
201101  245726   7951     81732    172      344      172       335409   688
201102  1066407  34094    371868   793      1586     793       1472369  3172
201103  1608750  51527    557677   1203     2406     1203      2217954  4812
TOTAL   2920883  93572    1011277  2168     4336     2168      4025732  8672
```

I want to create 2 new columns `SUM.A` and `SUM.B` and then create 1 new row `TOTAL`.
`SUM.A` is summed by `sum.A_1 : sum.A_3`; `SUM.B` is sum by `sum.B_1 : sum.B_3`.
`TOTAL` is summed by each column.

**DATA**

```
data <- "date    sum.A_1  sum.A_2  sum.A_3  sum.B_1  sum.B_2  sum.B_3
1: 201101  245726   7951     81732    172      344      172
2: 201102  1066407  34094    371868   793      1586     793
3: 201103  1608750  51527    557677   1203     2406     1203  
"
data <- read.table(text = data, header = T)
data <- as.data.table(data)
```

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**
I figure out the sum of each rows but still cannot solve sum of each columns.
I browsed the StackOverFlow and saw 2 useful resources.
[R: colSums when not all columns are numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488161/r-colsums-when-not-all-columns-are-numeric)
[How do I add a row to a data frame with totals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946873/how-do-i-add-a-row-to-a-data-frame-with-totals)

So, I try it on my data:

```
 rownames(data) <- data$date
 addmargins(as.table(as.matrix(data[-1])), 1)
 # Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
 data["TOTAL", .SDcols = grep("sum.", names(data))] <- sapply(colSums(data), is.numeric)
 # Error in colSums(data) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Is there a solution using `data.table` way?

**SOLVED**

```
janitor::adorn_totals(data, "row")
```

Comment: Tweaking `rowSums` and `colSums`according to your need is all what is required.

Comment: Adding a `TOTAL` row will convert the whole column to a character column which will be unusable. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: I just want to get the value. I know it will cause the column to be character. If i want to analyze my data or draw graphs, i will use the original one. thank you.

Comment: I update my question. Thanks.